# Python script using files in different directories

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, directory

I have data saved in the following format.

```
ID1/stats/file.stats
ID2/stats/file.stats
```

I have a script that will modify and convert file.stats to a csv file in the current directory but I want to be able to run the script once and convert all of the file.stats files in the folders ID1 through to  IDn.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
    import os
    for root, subFolders, fileNames in os.walk("ID2/stats/"):
        for fileName in fileNames:
            with open(os.path.join(root, fileName), 'rb') as f:
                # Do Something with the files
                for character in f.read():
                    #reading character by character
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did this help you?